# How to make a grid with images inside a div with HTML?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a grid of pictures with padding in between inside the main_block div. I cant get the images to aline next to eachother and then break it with a 
 becouse they go inline. inline block does not work. I tried making a new div for these images but i cant resize the pictures nor give them padding. I tried to make the pictures resizable but without results. iut is as if something is overriding the size of the pictures. The pictures stack upon eachother and im trying to maaake a grid. 
Thanks in advance for any help!
[This would be the optimal solution.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rs2Y1.jpg)

Here is the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/q2cr9ttL/1/

```css
 <style> 
 body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
 }
 
 #header {
   background-color: #ff6600;
   color: white;
   text-align: left;
   padding: 2px;
 }
 
 #nav {
   line-height: 30px;
   background-color: #fff000;
   height: 350px;
   width: 125px;
   float: left;
   padding: 5px;
 }
 
 #section {
   width: 350px;
   float: left;
   padding: 10px;
 }
 
 #footer {
   background-color: #737373;
   color: white;
   clear: both;
   text-align: center;
 }
 
 #container {
   margin: auto;
   width: 900px;
   text-align: left;
   overflow: hidden;
 }
 
 .inner_block {
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: center;
   width: 350px;
   height: 200px;
 }
 

 .main_block {
   text-align: center;
   width: 750px;
 }
 

  .grid_block {
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: center;
   width: 29%px;
   height:100px;
 }
 
 </style>
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <!---container--->
    <div id="header">
      <h1>JORDAS</h1>

    </div>
    <!--header-->

    <div id="nav">
      <a href="index.html">Etusivu</a>
      <br>
      <a href="teltat.html">Teltat</a>
      <br>
      <a href="page2.html">Palvelut</a>
      <br>
      <a href="Yhteystiedot.html">Yhteistiedot</a>
      <br>
    </div>

    <div id="section">


   <div class="main_block">

    <div class="grid_block">
        <img src=Grafik/basictalt.png>
    </div>

    <div class="grid_block">
        <img src=Grafik/basictalt.png >
    </div>    
 
  <div class="grid_block">
 
        <img src=Grafik/basictalt.png>
    </div>
   

</div><!--mainblock-->

    </div>

    <div id="footer">
      <h3>POP-UP TELTTOJEN YKKÖNEN </h3>
    </div>
    <!--footer-->
  </div>
  <!--container-->
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the flex display property.

You will need to include some prefixes for cross browser compatibility.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main_block {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.grid_block {
  width: 33%;
  padding: 1.4em
}

.grid_block img {
  max-width: 100%
}


/* ORIGINAL STYLES */
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#header {
  background-color: #ff6600;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 2px;
}

#nav {
  line-height: 30px;
  background-color: #fff000;
  height: 350px;
  width: 125px;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
}

#section {
  width: 350px;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

#footer {
  background-color: #737373;
  color: white;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
}

#container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 900px;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner_block {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
}

.main_block {
  text-align: center;
  width: 750px;
}

.grid_block {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 29%px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
 <div id="container">
    <!---container--->
    <div id="header">
      <h1>JORDAS</h1>

    </div>
    <!--header-->

    <div id="nav">
      <a href="index.html">Etusivu</a>
      <br>
      <a href="teltat.html">Teltat</a>
      <br>
      <a href="page2.html">Palvelut</a>
      <br>
      <a href="Yhteystiedot.html">Yhteistiedot</a>
      <br>
    </div>

    <div id="section">


   <div class="main_block">

    <div class="grid_block">
        <img src=http://lorempixel.com/image_output/city-q-c-640-480-9.jpg>
    </div>

    <div class="grid_block">
        <img src=http://lorempixel.com/image_output/city-q-c-640-480-9.jpg >
    </div>    
 
  <div class="grid_block">
 
        <img src=http://lorempixel.com/image_output/city-q-c-640-480-9.jpg>
    </div>
   

</div><!--mainblock-->

    </div>

    <div id="footer">
      <h3>POP-UP TELTTOJEN YKKÖNEN </h3>
    </div>
    <!--footer-->
  </div>
  <!--container-->
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your aanswer! But this did not solve my problem. The pictures stack on eachother vertically and they got no padding. the padding is not the issue but how to get them diagonal.

Comment: It works perfectly in jsfiddle, but when imported to notepad++ and i run it. It does not work. This is not the only solution ending up in the same results

Comment: you've answered your own problem... something in your own stylesheet is effecting the grid.

Comment: If it's working in the fiddle and when you run the snippet above, then you have other styles that are causing your problem.

Comment: Ok Thanks for the confirmation! I'll try to fix it! Do you have any idea of what it could be?

Comment: I'l add that i sended all the stylesheet to you so i wonder what it could be.